# Swift Object Array to JSON -> POST -> PHP json_decode() to PHP Object Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, swift, post

I've been writing swift/php/sql for 3 months now... (I know I'm a rookie).  I can create simple POST strings and issue http requests... etc.
Now I'm trying to push multiple objects to my server to add to my database. So I'm thinking the best way to transport the objects is to use a big json string. Maybe not... idk.  I have been unsuccessful at creating the multiple object json string to post.  Ideally, I'd like a string that PHP json_decode($myJsonString) will decode directly... I've created a playground to use as a test case. The call to JSON(myPlaceArray) results in "unknown".
Suggestions on how fix this or and easier way welcome!  thank you!

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
class myClass {

  public struct Place {
    var PlaceId   = String()
    var name      = String()
    var address   = String()
    var latitude  = Double()
    var longitude = Double()
  }

}

var myPlaceArray = [myClass.Place()]
var myPlace = myClass.Place()

for i in 0..<3 {
  myPlace.PlaceId = "\(i)"
  myPlace.address = "My Address \(i)"
  myPlace.name = "My Name \(i)"
  myPlace.latitude = 37.123
  myPlace.longitude = -127.321
  if(i==0){
    myPlaceArray[0] = myPlace
  }
  else {
    myPlaceArray.append(myPlace)
  }
}
print(myPlaceArray[0])

let json = JSON(myPlaceArray)
print(json)  // results: "unknown"

let jsonMyPlaceArray = JSON(myPlaceArray)
print(jsonMyPlaceArray)

//setup json post data

//send HTTP POST
let myUrl = NSURL(string: "https://myUrl.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myUrl! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "jsonPlaces=\(String(describing: jsonMyPlaceArray))"

print(postString)   // jsonPlaces=unknown

//.... make request
```

[playground_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISWa.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very useful the JSONUtils: 
https://github.com/peheje/JsonSerializerSwift
You can model your message as Swift classes and later serialize them using this library.
This is a piece of the code where I post a JSON message containing text data and an encoded image:

class TeamsSao : BaseSao {

```
class func update ( request : TeamUpdateRequest, callback : @escaping (TeamUpdateResponse!) -> Void ) {

    var strUrl : String = getServiceUrl() + "/index.php"
    strUrl += "?avoid_cache=" + StringUtils.randomString (length: 24)

    let url: URL = URL(string: strUrl)!

    var urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 120000
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData

    urlRequest.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let bodyStr:String = "msg=" + JSONUtils.toJson(request)//"pseudo=test"
    urlRequest.httpBody = bodyStr.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {   (data, response, error) in

            //print(data)
            //print(response)
            //print(error)

            var result : TeamUpdateResponse!

            if (error == nil) {
                if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                    if (httpResponse.statusCode < 200) || (httpResponse.statusCode >= 300) {
                        result  = TeamUpdateResponse()
                        result.status = TeamUpdateResponse.RESULT_EXCEPTION
                        result.errorDescription = "Response Status: \(httpResponse.statusCode)"
                    } else {
                        result = TeamUpdateParser.parse(data: data!)
                    }
                }

            } else {
                //print("A connection error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
                result  = TeamUpdateResponse()
                result.status = TeamUpdateResponse.RESULT_EXCEPTION
                result.errorDescription = error as! String!
            }
            callback (result)
    }
        ).resume()

}
```

}

A few points to understand:

1. TeamUpdateRequest is the class containing the data to send
2. TeamUpdateResponse is the class containing the response
3. With Swift 3 the you should work with callback functions. This method receive a callback function so, when the post is completed, the response will be parse and then the callback called.

Comment: Thank you Walter.  I can set up the url request and process the response.  What I'm having trouble with is converting the object array to a JSON string that can be sent as a parameter to the POST call.  Ideally I'd like to use the standard json_decode() php function to decode the JSON string directly on my server.

Comment: Thanks again Walter.  it looks like this may be just what I was looking for.  I'm testing it now.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, this worked perfect for me with a php backend too.

Comment: The serializer workes great!  It now appears the json string is getting truncated somewhere between my app and the server.  My php json string is 10K bytes.  Only about 1600 bytes are getting across the wire.  I'm looking into this possibly being a php setting on my server...

Comment: Turns out I have an & in my json serialized string that is being interpreted as a new parameter.  I thought UTF8 encoding encoded ampersands. request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? do I need to escape the ampresands?  \&  ?

Comment: I don't remember having that problem posting my data as part of the header and the encoded image is more than 10k in size. Yes I have problems at the PHP side because Swift do not replace ' '(spaces) for '+' which is required to decode on php.